# How to print tiled mapservices?

Tags: geoserver, printing

I have created a few GeoExt webmapping projects using Ubuntu10.04 / Tomcat6 / Geoserver /Postgis but have no good solution regarding printing the maps. Using GeowebCache I am not able to export to pdf using the mapfish module in geoserver due to tiling errors. If I do a simple html print of the mappanel then the toolbar in the mappanel is also printed and distorted....or I risk being sued by google if the maps are printed.

I need to be able to serve the maps with geoserver - ie not as tms or filebased tiling methods so that the tiles can be loaded as an ogc service.

Can anyone help?

yours,

Rob